# Replacement for Properties.list

Tags: java

I need to convert Properties objects to byte[], I used

```
byte[] bytes = SerializationUtils.serialize(properties);
```

But it doesn't seem to be working well as all the data gets corrupted and I see some symbols and special charters. So I used the below approach

```
StringWriter writer = new StringWriter();
properties.list(new PrintWriter(writer));
String fileContent = writer.getBuffer().toString();
byte[] bytes = fileContent.getBytes();
```

The above approach seems to work fine, but now calling properties.list is creating some issues as I was getting some text like "-- listing properties --" on the UI side, looks like Properties list method has hardcoded above string via out.println

```
public void list(PrintWriter out) {
        out.println("-- listing properties --");
        Hashtable h = new Hashtable();
        enumerate(h);
        for (Enumeration e = h.keys() ; e.hasMoreElements() ;) {
            String key = (String)e.nextElement();
            String val = (String)h.get(key);
            if (val.length() > 40) {
                val = val.substring(0, 37) + "...";
            }
            out.println(key + "=" + val);
        }
    }
```

Is there any other better way achieve it or some replacement for Properties.list?

Comment: We cannot help you until you explain WHY you need to do this.  This is an [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info) and we need to know the real problem you're trying to solve, not what you think the solution is.

Comment: Is there some problem with using `Properties.store()` that you haven't told us about?

Comment: Send it across what? Why not just serialize it?

Comment: Thanks for the comment, Well the actual problem is that I get a byte[] I convert it to Properties and update properties object. Now again I need to convert properties object back to byte[] and send it across. 

 contentData = content.getData();
 Properties properties = new Properties();
properties.load(new StringReader(new String(contentData,"UTF-8")));
properties.setProperty(key, value);

Comment: I say again. 1. What's the problem with `Properties.store()`? 2. Send it across **what?** You can see for yourself that `Properties.list()` doesn't handle values larger than 40 characters.

Comment: Thanks, @EJP Properties.store() works fine. Sorry wrong of words by send it across I mean to return the result byte[] to calling method. Thanks once again.

Answer (score 0):

The first approach is fine.

The point is that depending on what you want to do with that binary data, further encoding is required. For example, you could use Base64 encoding to turn your bytes into something that can be "moved" around easily.

Comment: Tried to encode with Base64.encode, but it didn't work. As suggested by EJP Properties.store() saved me here.

Comment: Glad you got your answer.